# Same Jenkins Configuration for 2 Different Jobs

Tags: xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Greetings StackOverflow Community!

Is it possible to have the same configuration setup for an XCode Project and an Appcelerator Project in Jenkins?

I haven't really tried creating Titanium Project, and I'm not sure if it can generate an XCode Project (Like in Unity). If it's possible, can we do a generic setup?

**EDITED:**
Now I know that an Appcelerator Project builds an XCode project as well. Can we add an additional layer in Jenkins which dynamically determines the project then points the Project directory?

Or would it be best to just have a setup guide for XCode project and a different setup guide for Appcelerator Project in Jenkins? (As I'm documenting a guide, by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Titanium indeed generates an Xcode project, you could do pretty much anything you'd do with an Xcode project once Titanium is done. So I'd document the Titanium compile step as a stage before continuing with either a Titanium-compiled or plain Xcode project.

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I thought as, well, just need to be sure of that. I thought of adding a script in the configure, and Execute Shell Script, but I think it would complicate. Thanks